# How does CALs Licenses work with Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

I looked all over the web for concrete information regarding CALs licenses in Azure  SQL but couldn't find much event on Microsoft Azure site.
Is this included within subscription ?
Or
Is it part of Azure Active Directory ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing questions are off-topic on DBA.SE

Answer (score 1):

There are no license restrictions in Azure SQL Database. No CAL licenses are required.  You pay for the database, and you may use it for any kind of application you wish and for any number of hosts or users. You only need to take in consideration Azure SQL Database limits for the maximum number of concurrent sessions allowed on each tier. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-single-databases?wt.mc_id=MVP) are the limits for the DTU model and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vcore-resource-limits-single-databases?wt.mc_id=MVP) you will find limits for the vCore model.